# class not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this code in controller:

```
use Larabook\Registration\RegistrUserCommand;
use Laracasts\Commander\CommandBus;

public function store()
    {
        extract(Input::only('username','email','password'));

        $command = new RegisterUserCommand($username, $email, $password);

        $this->commandBus->execute($command);
```

and in app/Larabook/Registration/RegisterUserCommand I have:

```
<?php namespace Larabook\Registration;

class RegisterUserCommand {

    public $username;

    public $email;

    public $password;

    function __construct($username,$email, $password)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->username = $username;
    }
}
```

when I run I took Class 'RegisterUserCommand' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your `use` statement. Change:

```
use Larabook\Registration\RegistrUserCommand;
```

to

```
use Larabook\Registration\RegisterUserCommand;
```

Comment: oh my god, Im searching the error over 1 hour, its my big mistake, thank you

Comment: You're welcome :) Are you using an IDE? I'm surprised it didn't throw a warning for that

Comment: I'm usimg SublimeText3 and maybe I need some plugin for that typo errors